# Create a token for Resource Management Node Azure SDK

Tags: node.js, azure

I've been using the Node Azure SDK over the last few days, everything is going well except for the fact that I cannot find any documentation on how to create an access token for the ResourceManagement API. It seems this doesn't use the PEM + SubId like the other API's in the SDK.

I did find the MSDN docs but they are .Net specific and assume the token is generated via a .dll file. Does anyone have any experience with generating this token via Node?

EDIT:

For reference I have asked on the [repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/1366) first but have yet to get a response (holiday season)

Comment: You are looking at the SDK, while I believe what you look for is the CLI: https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-cli Unless you want to build your own management portal, CLI shall do the job for you. There is already support for Azure Resource Manager in Azure CLI. And the source for CLI: https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli

Comment: I am specifically looking for token access via the Node SDK not the CLI. I am doing an automation project which creates and destroys resources. The API is already available, just no word on how to generate the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking to do this:

You need to do a service to service type OAuth call. This is slightly different to authenticating the user as most documents show.

The link below pretty much walks you through it. I've tested in postman (chrome) and have successfully got a token back.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use Active Directory http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/11/25/unattended-authentication-to-azure-management-apis-with-azure-active-directory.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this helps but it uses a c# lib to generate the token, this is the part I am looking for via Node.